# Deleting an item from an observable collection connected to a database in WP8

Tags: sql, windows-phone-8, observablecollection

I have a database in my WP8 application and I want to remove an item from the database when I press a button. All of the rows from the database is held in an observable collection called "person". How do I select the specific row I want and then remove it from the observable collection?

This is how I maybe thought it would be

```
 public void DeletePerson(int personID)
    {
       IQueryable<PersonData> test = from PersonData personToDelete in personDB.PersonDataTable
                                     where personToDelete.personID == personID
                                        select personToDelete;


        person.Remove(test);
        personDB.PersonDataTable.DeleteOnSubmit(personToDelete);

        personDB.SubmitChanges();
    }
```

however the `person.Remove()` only takes a `PersonData` item (which is the table in question) and not an `IQueryable`. So how do I get the `PersonData` item I want?

Comment: Try to use `person.Remove(test.First());`

Comment: Thank you that worked. Appreciate the help. To  bad you posted it as a comment and not an answer though

Comment: Posted as answer also :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change like this

```
person.Remove(test.First());
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to put

```
test.First()
```

as a parameter in both of the function calls before

```
personDB.SubmitChanges();
```

as posted by nkchandra